# Tensorflow: tf.trainable_variables() does not show my mode weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I am trying to extract my model weights to be able to run my first pre-trained model. However, I am unable to extract my weights since executing `tf.trainable_variables()` give me the following output:

```
[<tf.Variable 'VGGNet/B1C1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 1, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'VGGNet/B1C1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'VGGNet/B1C2/kernel:0' shape=(1, 3, 32, 32)....
```

It shows the shape, but not the `numpy` array that I am expecting. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be extracting weights for using your pre-trained model; instead use the `model.save_weights()` and `model.load_weights()` utility methods provided by the API. Here's a link to the document you can use to learn more about it [`Save and load models`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load).

Coming to your question - why you are not seeing the weights: it is because `tf.trainable_variables()` is supposed to give you variables and not their values (aka weights).